# Making webview a default browser

Tags: android, webview

I was wondering if there was a way to make webview a default browser for a phone, act like browser. Respond on links and open them. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WebView` is a widget. It is not an activity, nor is it an app. You cannot make a widget be a default for anything.

You are welcome to write an Android app, that has an activity, that has a `WebView` widget in it. You can set up that activity with an `<intent-filter>` that allows it to respond to `ACTION_VIEW` requests for `https` and `http` URLs. In this sense, you will have created a limited Web browser.

However, **the user** would have to elect to make your "browser" be the default. Fortunately, you cannot force your app to be the default, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Yes i know this, i just was in hurry so fast typing and not thinking, thanks for replay anyway.